# Add two queries at store method in controller

Tags: mysql, laravel, model, controller, eloquent

I have this migration table for OFFERS:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('offers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('article_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->string('comment');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('key');
            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamp('start');

            $table->foreign('user_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('users')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('article_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('articles')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

Also this at model I have:

```
class Offer extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = [
        'price',
        'comment',
        'article_id',
        'key',
        'start'
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'start'
    ];

    public function setStartAttribute($date){
        $this->attributes['start']= Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y h:i a', $date);
    }
    public function getStartAttribute($date){
        return (new Carbon($date))->toRfc2822String();
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    public function article(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Article');
    }
}
```

Now at controller I have just store function:

```
public function store(Requests\OfferRequest $request)
    {

            $offer = new Offer($request->all());

            Auth::user()->offer()->save($offer);

            Alert::success('Offer is succesfully added!', 'Good job!')->persistent("Close");

        return Redirect::back();

    }
```

Now I also have the same model MAXOFFER. The same is migartion and model.

What I want to do is to add at OffersController store method a query that will chech does `start` excist in maxoffers table and if not then to add new row with data from request, but if excist row with same `start` value then to check `price` and if `price` is higher than current to update that row...

Please help me to rite that query inside store function at offercontroller...

Comment: If you can explain me the if exists condition, I can modify the below answer.

Comment: so first I add offer then I check in maxoffer table does excist row with same article_id and start and if not I add new row, but if row excist then I need to check is the new price higher than current and if yes I need to update that row complet (with new data)...

Comment: if exist - if already have row with same START and ARTICLE_ID value (then check price) -also if not then add new row at mysql database table

Comment: Check the updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query is created by guessing you have a relation `maxoffer` in `Maxoffer` model.

```
$maxoffer = Auth::user()->maxoffer()
                        ->where('address_id', $request->input('address_id'))
                        ->where('start', $request->input('start'))->first();

   if($maxoffer==null)
    {
      Ath::user()->maxoffer()->create($request->all());
    }
    else
    {
      if($maxoffer->price < $request->input('price'))
      {
         $newOffer = Auth::user()->maxoffer()
                    ->where('address_id', $request->input('address_id'))
                    ->where('start', $request->input('start'))
                                     ->update(['price'=>$request->input('price')]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: not just to update price, I need to update complet row with new data, not just price... so if the price is higher etc. 200 (curent 100)  for 2016-02-02 and article_id = 2 then updtate row - every column with new data...

Comment: You can add all fields in the array like: `->update(['comment'=>$request->input('comment'), 'price'=>$request->input('price'), 'title'=>$request->input('title')]);` Add all columns and values here.

Comment: hm, I get error: 1/1
FatalErrorException in OffersController.php line 65:
syntax error, unexpected '::' (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM)

Comment: no,now I get... ErrorException in OffersController.php line 59:
Undefined variable: requests - SIMPLY when I find maxoffer ID with same start and article_id then I need to update that row, so to update that ID row... offcource if the price is higher

Comment: It was spposed to be `$request->all()` my typo.

Comment: I try now, and NO, that code create row at maxoffer table but dont update them if the price is higher

Comment: You want to update the value in the Maxoffer table. Right?

Comment: I just updated again. Also, please check if the condition you want is correct.

Comment: no, here: $maxoffer = Auth::user()->maxoffer()
                        ->where('address_id', $request->input('address_id'))
                        ->where('start', $request->input('start'))->first();
 -  I need to fetch row ID value and then in last part of code update that ID with new data (request->all())...

Comment: I've provided the syntax for getting all values and updating rows. I'm not sure if I get what you really want. So, can you play around with the given code?